# Openstack: 400 Bad Request - X-Instance-ID header is missing from request

Tags: http-post, openstack, bad-request, openstack-nova

When i do http post request to openstack with command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "X-Auth-Token: $Token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"server": {"name": "server", "flavorRef": "1", "imageRef": "Cirros", "security_groups": [{"name": "default" }], "availability_zone": "nova", "networks": "Network1"}}' $OS_AUTH_URL:8775/servers
```

this message appears to me:

```
{"message": "X-Instance-ID header is missing from request.<br /><br />\n\n\n", "code": "400 Bad Request", "title": "Bad Request"}
```

I have read the nova api documentation but i didn't find anything.

Comment: are you trying to launch an instance or getting back a list of instances that meet the requirements in the `-d`?

Comment: I think that before i launch i have to create it.

Comment: no, launch and create basically mean the same thing here in terms of openstack nova. In other words, here you are trying to list your instances or a particular instance and that's why it is asking for an ID.

Comment: Oh ok you're right. But i can't understand how to only create a server. In the api nova documentation, the HTTP request to create a new server seems like that i've posted.

Comment: let me try something and hopefully get back to you how to do it as an answer ;) `curl` could be tricky sometimes. Have you tried the python client api? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer is to change:**

`$OS_AUTH_URL:8775` to `$OS_AUTH_URL:8774/v2/[your_project_id]/servers`

Port `8774` should be the default port for the OpenStack Nova service. You can also check the endpoint using `curl`. So unless you configure the endpoint to port `8775` intentionally, the port number should be 
`8774`

**The longer version of the answer would be:**

First, you should get the keystone token and you will get your project ID from the result as well.

```
curl -s -X POST [your_auth_url]/v2.0/tokens \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"auth": {"tenantName": "'"admin"'", "passwordCredentials":
    {"username": "'"admin"'", "password": "'"password"'"}}}' | python -m json.tool
```

for example, `[your_auth_url] = https://127.0.0.1:5000`

P.S. This is using the `v2.0` keystone auth which is deprecated. For `v3`, you need to change the `v2.0` to `v3` and add `project_domain_name` and `user_domain_name` along with the username, password. Details here: https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/pike/api_curl_examples.html#v3-api-examples-using-curl

After this, you will get your `project_id` and `token`. And you can list images, flavors, keypairs, and etc.

Then, you want to launch an instance:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Auth-Token:$1" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d  '
{       
 "server": {  
   "name": "UsingcUrl",
   "imageRef": "[your_image_id]",
   "flavorRef": "[your_flavor_id]", 
   "key_name" : "[your_keypair_name]"
 }          
}' http://127.0.0.1:8774/v2/[your_project_id]/servers | python -m json.tool
```

HTH.

Comment: I no longer receive that error. But now it ask me a network that i have to insert into body, but the "networks" requires an object.

Comment: @Tatta, sorry for the delay. Then you need to create a network first. Do you have the access to the dashboard? Or you can search how to use REST api to create an OpenStack private network with using neutron.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use this command now beacause i saw that "networks" must be an object.

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Auth-Token:$Token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d  '{{"server": {"name": "UsingcUrl","imageRef": "c6839d78-1bc1-4661-9be3-3e9252f0c227","flavorRef": "e07fb38a-1e23-4b92-a1ff-c2fce2d97963","key_name" : "NEWKEY"}}{"networks": {"name": "89c2d870-1cfe-424a-9095-50d60e7b2538"}}}' http://$AUTH_URL:8774/v2/$ID_PROJECT/servers | python -m json.tool
```

but i receive this message:

```
{
"badRequest": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Malformed request body"
}}
```